# Golang prevent wait group blocking forever

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang and have the following code. I want to be able to fetch questions for different question tags in a new Goroutine. But I'm confused by Sync Wait Groups.

My program seems to be blocking forever, and never reaches the print statement at the bottom. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

I'm trying to build from the fairly straight-forward example in the documentation here https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup
    package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

type question struct {
    lang, text, url string
}

var url string = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/"

func scrapePage(url string) *goquery.Document {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return doc
}

func getQuestions(lang string, ch chan<- question, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    doc := scrapePage(url + lang)
    doc.Find(".summary .question-hyperlink").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        url, _ := s.Attr("href")
        text := s.Text()
        ch <- question{lang, text, url}
    })
}

func main() {
    tags := os.Args[1:]

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(tags))

    ch := make(chan question)
    for index := range tags {
        lang := tags[index]
        go getQuestions(lang, ch, wg)
    }

    go func() {
        for i := range ch {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    // Never reached :(
    fmt.Println("Done")

}
```

**update**
Still no luck with the following after someone pointed out I was incorrectly passing a copy of the wg.WaitGroup

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

type question struct {
    lang, text, url string
}

var url string = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/"

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    tags := os.Args[1:]

    wg.Add(len(tags))

    ch := make(chan question)
    for index := range tags {
        lang := tags[index]
        go getQuestions(lang, ch)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("After WAIT")
    close(ch)

    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Println(<-ch, i)
    }
    ch = nil
    fmt.Println("Done")

}

func getQuestions(lang string, ch chan question) {
    doc := scrapePage(url + lang)
    doc.Find(".summary .question-hyperlink").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        url, _ := s.Attr("href")
        text := s.Text()
        ch <- question{lang, text, url}
    })
    wg.Done()
}

func scrapePage(url string) *goquery.Document {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return doc
}
```

Comment: you're passing the WaitGroup by value. `go vet` reports these errors.

Comment: I've tweaked the code as suggested in the answer to the duplicate question, but now the program seems to hang completely, with no output whatsoever.

Comment: You're now waiting before receiving anything .from `ch`, so the goroutines are blocked sending.

Comment: This is exactly what the solution from the duplicate question does. Where exactly should the wg.Wait() statement go?

Comment: The other question started with a buffered channel, so the sends don't block. Alternatively you could put the Wait+close in it's own goroutine and let main block on the range loop.

Comment: Wrapping the wait+close in a goroutine did the trick. Thanks for your help and patience, much appreciated!